# Приходится очень точно попадать на ImageButton

Tags: android

В некоторых местах моего приложения имеются `ImageButton:` удалить товар из корзины, свернуть `EditText`...

Столкнулся с проблемой, что границы клика малы т.к. размер кнопки 20x20dp и с первого раза нажать удается не всегда. Пробовал задать им отступ - `padding = 20dp` - но это не помогло.

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/ib_hide_congratulation_text_window"
    android:layout_width="20dp"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="35dp"
    android:background="@drawable/close"
    android:padding="20dp" />
```

Поделитесь опытом, как вы делаете или что у меня не правильно?

Comment: Используйте padding вместо margin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте увеличить размер кнопки и добавить к ней паддинг для компенсации изменения размера картинки:

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/ib_hide_congratulation_text_window"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="35dp"
    android:background="@drawable/close"
    android:padding="10dp" />
```

P.S. В параметрах разработчика есть пункт "отображать границы макета". Включите его для оценки размеров элементов на экране

Comment: Для `ImageButton` это не работает. Для `ImageView`, да. Но с учётом, что картинка задаётся через `src` а не как тут, бекграундом.

Comment: почему не используете ImageView? в разметке не видно использования текста

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте поместить вашу кнопку в `LinearLayout` высота и ширина у которого будет, например `50dp` и метод `onClick` вашей кнопки переопределите для этого `LinearLayout:`

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/buttonLayout"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp">

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/ib_hide_congratulation_text_window"
    android:layout_width="20dp"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="35dp"
    android:background="@drawable/close"
    android:padding="20dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы слишком жестко задали размеры кнопки

```
android:layout_width="20dp"
android:layout_height="20dp"
```

Выставленный вам `padding` будет работать именно внутри этих размеров, а не расширит область нажатия.

Увеличьте общий размер кнопки.

Answer (score 0):

Можете "прикрутить" onTouchListener ко всему макету и в event.getRawX() и getRawY() отслеживать попадание нажатия в необходимую область вокруг ImageButton